# Reading settings.ini correctly

Tags: python-3.x, settings, ini

For example I have a settings.ini file of my program which includes:

```
theme=white
SaveDirectory=C:\Screenshots
```

I read it like that:

```
with open("settings.ini", "r") as settings:
    setting = settings.readlines()
    theme = setting[0]
    theme = theme[len("theme="):].strip()
    bg = theme
    print(theme)
    SaveDirectory = setting[1]
    SaveDirectory = SaveDirectory[len("SaveDirectory="):].strip()
    print(SaveDirectory)
    settings.close()
```

But I know that is bad and risky when my .ini gets longer. I need a function which reads lines with starts of them. Like: `function("theme=")`. Is there something like that for python3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3 has a [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) module which does exactly what you want, though you'll need to add a `[section]` header to the top of your file first so that it conforms to the [supported file structure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#supported-ini-file-structure).